# BufferedReader: Determine byte offset of lines read

Tags: java, utf-8, bufferedreader

I'm using a BufferedReader to read a byte stream (UTF-8 text) line by line. For a specific reason, I need to know where exactly in the byte stream the line starts.

The problem: I can't use the position of the InputStream I plug into the BufferedReader as - well - the reader buffers and reads more than a line in one go.

My question: **How can I determine the precise byte offset of each line read?**

One apparent (but incorrect) solution would be to use (line + "\n").getBytes("UTF-8").length. There is two problems with this approach: 1) Just to count the number of bytes, it's quite an overhead to convert the string back to bytes and 2) a newline is not always marked with "\n" - it might also be "\r\n", etc.

**Is there any other solution to this?**

EDIT: Every LineReader-like class I've seen so far seems to be buffered. Does anyone know of an unbuffered LineReader-like class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the file as raw bytes, newline in UTF-8 will always either be `13` and `10`, `13` or `10`... but that's exactly the same problem you would have if you read the file as string if the files are going to have different EOL conventions.

The raw byte equivalent of `BufferedReader` is [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)

You can also count UTF-8 bytes of a string without encoding:

```
public static int byteCountUTF8(String input) {
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        int cc = Character.codePointAt(input, i);
        if (cc <= 0x7F) {
            ret++;
        } else if (cc <= 0x7FF) {
            ret += 2;
        } else if (cc <= 0xFFFF) {
            ret += 3;
        } else if (cc <= 0x10FFFF) {
            ret += 4;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the buffer size:

```
BufferedReader (Reader in, int sz)
```

> Parameters:
>
> **in** - A Reader
>
> **sz** - Input-buffer size

set the buffering size to 1.

Comment: That's an internal optimization detail, not something that changes functionality to outside. If you leave the size argument out, it's the same as `new BufferedReader(in, 8192)`

Comment: @Esailija 8192 is the default buffer size, but if I set it to 1, will it read one char at each invocation?

Comment: Yes but that will only make it slower